# Opening 3 Firefox windows and a program on 4 different screens

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Im trying to write a Python script that opens 3 different firefox windows using Selenium. The windows are supposed to be spread out on different monitors. So far i've sucessfully managed to open one window with two tabs, drag it to the monitor i need it to be on and maximize it. My struggle now is with the next 2 windows as iam confused on how to open them in the way i need them and log in to one of them, see my code for further explanations:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import subprocess

#bottom_left_1
#open one window with two tabs 
#done

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'actual gecko path')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com/','new window')")
print ("opened tab1")
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.set_window_position(-1000,-1000)
driver.fullscreen_window()

#top_left_2
#open one window with one tab
#work in progress

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
print ("opened tab2")
driver.set_window_position(1000,1000)
driver.fullscreen_window()

#top_right_3
#open one window with one tab
#log in to a webpage with username and password
#work in progress

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
print ("opened tab3")
time.sleep(5)
driver.set_window_position(0,0)
driver.fullscreen_window() 

#bottom_right_4
#open a .exe and maximize it on screen 4
#program automatically opens on screen 4
#done

subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "start", "/max", "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"])
```

Comment: couldn't you just use different variables to store the different windows and their positions?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, that indeed worked out with adding a second_driver for my second window and doing the same for the third one. Only problem left now is to log in to a website using selenium